# Embedding Inline image in email body

Tags: android

In my application i have to send image in body not as an attachment. I have spent more than one week and found no success. I have implemented same via Java mail API. But need to implement with intent. What i have tried is:

```
Spanned emailText11 =   Html.fromHtml("<body><p><img src=\"http://www.datarecoverydownloadwebsite.com/drdwebsite/image/pen-drive1.jpg\" alt=\"Smiley face\" align=\"bottom\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" /></p></body>", new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                 Drawable drawFromPath;
                 int path = Inline_Image_Gmail.this.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", "com.package..."); 
                 drawFromPath = (Drawable) Inline_Image_Gmail.this.getResources().getDrawable(path);
                 drawFromPath.setBounds(0, 0, drawFromPath.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawFromPath.getIntrinsicHeight());
                 return drawFromPath;

            }
    }, null);
```

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,emailText11 );

I googled alot and ans is it is not possible. If not can anyone clear me the reason for this.

Thanks.

Comment: first accept old answer's of your question

Comment: if no one has given me correct ans should i accept